# Distance between two distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, metric-spaces

I would like your opinion with a two metrics.

It is known that the Kantorovich–Rubinstein metric is a distance function defined between probability distributions on a given metric space M.

On the other hand, considering two continuous probability distributions $q(x)$ and $p(x)$,  The Kullback–Leiber divergence is defined as the measure of the information lost when $q(x)$ is used to approximate $p(x)$.
\begin{equation*}
    \mathrm{KL} (p(x)|| q(x)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} p(x) \ln \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} dx
\end{equation*}

Thank you very much for your help/hints/suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

**General comments:** Convergence of the Kantorovich-Rubinstein metric (Wasserstein distance) is equivalent to weak convergence, under some regularity conditions, which makes it a strong candidate.
The same is not true for the KL-divergence.
Moreover, the KL-divergence is in general not a distance, since it is not symmetric (although it can be, see below).

The answer depends on your specific problem.
Here are some examples.

**A case where it doesn't matter**:
If you compare normal distributions with different mean $\mathcal{N}(\theta_1,1)$, $\mathcal{N}(\theta_2,1)$, both the Kantorovich-Rubinstein metric (2-Wasserstein distance) and the KL-divergence just give you the same answer, namely $|\theta_1-\theta_2|$.
So, in this case, it doesn't matter.

**A case where the Kantorovic-Rubinstein metric is superior**.
If you compare distributions whose support differs.
E.g. if you compare uniform distributions supported on $(\theta,\theta+1)$ for $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, then convergence in the Kantorovich-Rubinstein metric is still equivalent to $\theta_n\rightarrow\theta$ (since convergence of this metric is equivalent to weak-convergence, under some regularity conditions).
On the other hand, the KL-divergence is infinite, unless $\theta=\theta'$

**A case where you'd want to use the KL-divergence**. In some cases, the two distributions you are comparing have different roles.
For example, in hypothesis testing.
Here, the KL-divergence can be used to calculate the expected value of the likelihood ratio between the null and the alternative hypothesis, under the alternative hypothesis [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/intuition-on-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence/189758#189758). In this case, the asymmetry of the KL-divergence is not a bug, but a feature.

Comment: If you are just comparing the two distributions, I would go for a metric (Kantorovich-Rubinstein or other). If there two have different roles (such as in the testing example above), the KL-divergence is probably more natural.

Comment: Thank you very much, so for example if I have the distribution of two non-normal distributions one identifies the distribution of normal weight and the other distribution is when they have a treatment for losing weight. Some papers have used the KL divergence to estimate the distance between those distributions, do you think that still the Kantorovich-Rubinstein metric could work? Thanks again.

Comment: It depends. Even if they are not normally distributed - is the normal distribution a good approximation? If not, what assumptions can you make about the distributions? What you're describing sounds like a hypothesis-testing-problem. This might lead to you favoring the KL-divergence.